# What is the capability of the control loop to compensate offset in measurement?

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory, linear-control, pi-controller

Let's say I have a control loop

[image]

where $D$ is the transfer function of the controller and $G$ is the
transfer function of the plant. The $R$, $Y$, $E$, and $V$ are the Laplace
transforms of the reference value, the controlled variable, the control error and the measurement noise. As far as the Laplace transform of the control error following equations hold

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
Y &=& \frac{DG}{1 + DG}\cdot R - \frac{DG}{1 + DG}\cdot V \\
E &=& R - Y = \frac{1}{1 + DG}\cdot R + \frac{DG}{1 + DG}\cdot V
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Now suppose there is a constant offset in the measurement i.e. $V = \frac{1}{s}$. My question is whether the control loop can compensate this offset in case following holds
$\lim\limits_{s\to 0} (DG) \to \infty$?

Comment: You have a mistake in your expression for $E$. Namely instead of $E=R-Y$ one should use $E=R-Y-V$.

Comment: The dynamics of the transfer from the reference to the output is the same as that of the offset. So, whatever you do on the offset will be done to the reference.

Comment: @KBS thank you for your reaction. In other words you say that answer to my question is yes i.e. the controller can compensate the influence of the offset in case there is at least one integrator in the open loop transfer function. Is that correct?

Comment: No. If you reject the disturbance you will also reject the reference. Just pick a simple example and do the calculations.

Comment: It will not compensate for $V$ in the sense that if $R=2$ and $V=1$ then $Y \to 1$ not $2$. It is like adding an offset to the reference.

Comment: I think that I have interpreted the formula for $E$ in wrong manner. In case $\lim\limits_{s \to 0} (DG)\to \infty$ the contribution to the error $E$ coming from the $R$ goes to zero but at the same time the contribution from the $V$ goes to unity i.e. the measurement noise isn't compensated at all.

Comment: @obareey please can you tell me whether there is some recommended approach for measurement offset rejection in the PI control loop?